# How can I change the ordering of my leaderboards in Game Center?

Tags: game-center, leaderboard

I'm working on an iPhone game. In iTunesConnect I created Game Center leaderboards for levels 10 through 20 of my game. Then I decided to add leaderboards for levels 5 through 9. Now when I look at them in the gamecenter app they are sorted according to the sequence in which I entered them, not alphabetically, so levels 5 - 9 appear at the end after level 20. I don't see any way on the itunesconnect site to change the ordering. Do I have to delete all of the leaderboards and create them over again?  What a pain that would be!

This is in the sandbox. I haven't submitted the game yet.

Comment: I'm also not sure of a way to do this.  If it turns out to not be possible.  Make a report at bugreport.apple.com, post it also on Open Radar and link to it here.  I'll duplicate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using your web browser, just grab the leaderboard and drag it and it will reorder them.

Comment: Roger Gilbrat you're right! I tried doing that before but it didn't work because I was grabbing at the wrong place. You have to grab-and-drag on the 3 grey bars at the left end of a row. Once you see it work it seems so obvious.

Comment: Yeah, it took me a while to figure it out.